# How can i get phonemes for words to work with sphinx

Tags: java, cmusphinx

I want to create my own dictionary for Sphinx voice recognition software. So I want to get the phonemes for words like this (2nd Column):

```
ONE                  HH W AH N
ONE(2)               W AH N
TWO                  T UW
THREE                TH R IY
FOUR                 F AO R
FIVE                 F AY V
SIX                  S IH K S
SEVEN                S EH V AH N
EIGHT                EY T
NINE                 N AY N
ZERO                 Z IH R OW
ZERO(2)              Z IY R OW
OH                   OW
```

Is there any software that takes a voice and returns the 2nd column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [g2p-seq2seq](https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq).

To convert a single word:

```
g2p-seq2seq --model g2p-seq2seq-cmudict --interactive
```

and then type a word

```
 > hello 
 HH EH L OW
```

to convert a list of words:

```
g2p-seq2seq --model g2p-seq2seq-cmudict --decode word.list
```

for more information see [cmusphinx tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialdict)

Comment: if there is any program that take the voice not Text ?